# mean squared error or brier score?

Tags: scikit-learn, mse, scoring-rules

i have a classification problem using xgboost, i was optimizing on brier score or 'neg_brier_score' in sklearn. however what is the difference between 'neg_brier_score' and '‘neg_mean_squared_error’  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

i don't understand the difference.